# Codeigniter not displaying stylsheet when clicking on links

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I just built a sit in Codeigniter, but when I click on a menu item the stylesheet breaks and it displays all of the content broken out on the page.

http://marciabrownproductions.com/

I uploaded it to a test server and all the links works perfectly.But when I uploaded the finished site ot my clients server the css issue starts. Is there something wrong with my clients server? Or is there a problem with how I coded the site? Why does it work on one server, but not the other.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but now I didn't see any difference between these links that you upload? Did you fix your problem?

Comment: It's still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend using absolute paths instead of relative paths when referencing your assets. At the moment, they are being picked up with the `index.php` included.

So, let's say your link is `http://domain.tld/index.php/home/actors`, you should be calling your assets from their actual URLs - `http://domain.tld/index.php/_/css/style.css` would not work, for example. `http://domain.tld/_/css/style.css`, however, would work. (That's just a sample URL.)

I'd also recommend removing the `index.php` from your links, simply by using the htaccess `RewriteEngine`, and removing `index.php` from your app's config file.

Have a look at how your current source is being generated in a browser (right-click, View Source) to see what I mean.

### Update:

Based on your comment, that may be an `htaccess` issue. Check to see if your hosting provider supports it.

In the meantime, put the `index.php` back in the app's main config file. However, leave your CSS asset link as it is. Make sure all your asset links look like this:

```
<link href="http://marciabrownproductions.com/_/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://marciabrownproductions.com/_/js/jquery.validate.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://marciabrownproductions.com/_/js/effects.js'></script>
<link href="http://marciabrownproductions.com/_/css/bjqs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://marciabrownproductions.com/_/js/bjqs-1.3.js"></script>
```

Your images are broken because their links are also including the `index.php/home`. You need to make sure that that is taken out. (What are you using to generate your links anyway?)

Comment: @Animuson, don't use back ticks, use backslashes to escape the underscores.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I agree, my bad.

Comment: Hey, I used a absolute path for the css, now when I click on another link, it's not bringing up the correct view. It just shows the home page again but with everything broken.

http://marciabrownproductions.com/